# Can AWS PrivateLink Endpoint IP address change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-private-link

When you setup a [AWS PrivateLink Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html#vpce-interface-limitations), you get a hostname to target. E.g. `com.amazonaws.vpce.us-east-2.vpce-svc-123xyz567` which resolves to a private IP in the subnet you create it in, e.g. `192.168.0.1`. Do those change? It seems likely we're given a hostname, but does it happen in practice?

For example, if I have limitation in a legacy system that it can only target an IP address and not a hostname, how likely/often is it that I would need to update?